# GCC: array type has incomplete element type?

Tags: arrays, gcc, pointers, struct, typedef

GCC gives me an "array type has incomplete element type"-error message when i try to compile this:

```
typedef struct _node node;
struct _node{
 int foo;
 node (*children)[2];
 int bar;
};
```

In memory the struct should look like this

```
0x345345000000 foo
0x345345000004 pointer to 1. child node
0x345345000008 pointer to 2. child node
0x34534500000C bar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the C type expression works the other way round.

This:

```
node (*children)[2];
```

reads as the following: the contents of `children`, when dereferenced (`*` is applied to them), yield something on which the array operator `[]` can be applied, yielding a `node`. Which means that `children` is a pointer to an array of two `node`. However, you do not want a pointer to an array, you want an array of two pointers. For that, you should put the parentheses thus:

```
node *(children[2]);
```

which then reads as: the contents of `children` are an array of two values; applying `*` on one of them yields a `node`. This is what you want: an array of two pointers to `node`. Note that this is equivalent to:

```
node *children[2];
```

because in the C syntax, when it comes to type expressions, the `[]` operator takes precedence over the `*` operator.

In your initial version, the C compiler grumbles because at the time it reads the declaration, it does not know what size `node` is (the structure definition is not complete yet), and, as such, has trouble imagining a type "array of two `node`". This is a rather indirect symptom of the problem.

Side note: you should refrain from using `_node` or any other identifier beginning with an underscore in your code. These identifiers are reserved for "the implementation". In practice, system headers may use them, and collisions could prove harmful. Personally, I tend to add the underscore at the *end*, like this: `typedef struct node_ node;`

Comment: I'm confused why you'd use an underscore at all. `typedef struct node node;` is perfectly valid and makes it possible to use `struct node` if you ever want/need to.

Comment: @R..: I have encountered old C compilers where `typedef struct node node;` was not accepted. Also, in C++ (not C), the namespaces for structure tags and type names are not fully disjoint; so I took the habit to use distinct identifiers for structure tags and type names, hence the final underscore. I find that it also helps my brain: it makes it more obvious, to my aging neurons, whether a given identifier is a structure tag or a typedef-ed name.

Comment: I'm guessing those compilers also lack `void` pointers. As for C++, a `struct` automatically creates a type, but redundant typedefs are permitted by the language, with `typedef struct foo foo;` as a special case that's very useful.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
 node (*children)[2];
```

Use this:

```
 struct _node* children[2];
```

Comment: If I replace "node" by "struct _node" in line 4 it doesn't work.
Is that what you mean?

Comment: Actually its "node* children[2];", but thank you. It worked when I removed the brackets. ... Damn pointers!